# How to get the ggplot2 sat_smooth blue line as a function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The follwing command:

```
ggplot(s, aes(x = I5, y = Success))+geom_point(size=3, alpha=0.4)+
  stat_smooth(method="loess", colour="blue", size=1.5)+
  xlab("I5")+
  ylab("Probability of Success")+
  theme_bw()
```

gives me the following plot:

[image]

I would like to get what corresponds to the *blue line* as a function so that I can apply it to any value.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the actual loess fit, it's probably better to run it yourself. Let's create some sample data (it would have been nice if you had include some in your original question)

```
dd <- data.frame(
    x=1:50,
    y = cumsum(rnorm(50))
)
```

And now we can run the `loess` function ourself

```
 sm <- loess(y~x, dd)
```

Now we can compare the line that `ggplot` draws to our `loess` curve

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) + 
  stat_smooth(method="loess") + 
  geom_point(data=data.frame(x=sm$x, y=predict(sm)), col="red")
```

[image]

We can see these line up perfectly. This we can just use the `predict()` function with our `loess` object to get a value for any point. For example

```
predict(sm, 5)
# [1] -2.922876
```